# Creating a Bar plot by sex and age category in python

Tags: python

I want to generate a bar plot using age bins (eg. 40-50, 60-70) and sex. I am having various errors return. I have an excel sheet of the data that i have previously loaded in.

Here is my code that I have tried so far:

```
def create_bar_plot_by_sex(covid19_data, age_ranges):
    age_range_labels = [str(x[0])+"-"+str(x[1]) for x in age_ranges]
    # from the covid19_data, select the age_range for female
    female_age_ranges = covid19_data[covid19_data['sex']=="female"] 
    counts_female = female_age_ranges.value_counts()[age_range_labels]


    # from the covid19_data, select the age_range for male rows 
    male_age_ranges = covid19_data[covid19_data['sex']=='male']
    counts_male = male_age_ranges.value_counts()[age_range_labels]

    # create plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
    index = np.arange(len(age_ranges))
    bar_width = 0.35
    opacity = 0.8

    # the bar function draws a bar plot, the first two arugments are the x position of the bar, and its height
    rects1 = plt.bar(index,counts_male, bar_width,
    alpha=opacity,color='b',label='Male')

    rects2 = plt.bar(index+bar_width,counts_female, bar_width,  
    alpha=opacity,color='g',label='Female')

    plt.xlabel('Age Range')
    plt.ylabel('Count')
    plt.title('Corona Cases per Age Group')
    #plt.xticks(index + bar_width, age_ranges)
    plt.xticks(index, ["["+str(x[0])+","+str(x[1])+")" for x in age_ranges])
    plt.legend()

    plt.tight_layout()
    return counts_female, counts_male

cnts_f, cnts_m = create_bar_plot_by_sex(covid19_data, age_ranges)
```

I am having a KeyError return

Comment: Can you give an example for the data of your excel sheet?

Comment: The data for age either appears as a range (50-60) or a month and year (eg. aug-68). Sex appears as either 'male' 'female' ,blank, or some form of na

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the column names in your Excel sheet match the column names used in your code.then check and make sure that the "sex" column in your Excel sheet contains only "male" and "female" values, as these are the only values being used in the Python code. If there are other values, this could result in a KeyError

hope this helps

Comment: Hi! thanks for the help! Unfortunately this is not the issue. To clarify, the KeyError is in line 8 regarding the age range, and appears like this: KeyError: "['0-10' '10-20' '20-30' '30-40' '40-50' '50-60' '60-70' '70-80' '80-90'\n '90-100'] not in index"